# How to use DatePicker widget in android?

Tags: android

`enter code here`I have used the DatePicker widget in android.Upon clicking that I want the datePickerdialog to show up and date should be set and the same I want to set to a textview. 
Thanks in advance.

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this,new   DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {     
        @Override
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                      startDateTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
startDateTextView.setText(dayOfMonth + "-"+ (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);
}
}, year, month, day);
dpd.show();
```

the above code i used,bt this works before i click on datepicker. please let me know how to use OnClickListener of datepicker to this

Comment: @user3350830 can you check my answer I think it is simple to implement

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.

```
package com.example.datetimepicker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button date,time;
    TextView preview;
    int year,monthofyear,dayofmonth,hourofday,minute;
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    DateFormat dt = DateFormat.getInstance();

    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener tpd;
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dpd;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        date = (Button)findViewById(R.id.date);
        date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,dpd,
                        cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();

            }
        });
        time = (Button)findViewById(R.id.time);
        time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,tpd,
                        cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                        false).show();
            }
        });
        preview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        dpd = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                    int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

                preview.setText(new StringBuilder().append(year+"/")
                        .append(monthOfYear+"/").append(dayOfMonth));
            }
        };

        tpd = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker arg0, int hourofday, int minute) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourofday);
                cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

                preview.setText(new StringBuilder().append(hourofday+"/")
                        .append(minute));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this:

//variables

```
DatePicker dpResult; 
static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 999;
```

//methods

```
public void setCurrentDateOnView() {

        dpResult = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dpResult);
        dpResult.setVisibility(View.GONE );
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);



        // set current date into datepicker
        dpResult.init(year-7, month, day, null);

    }

@Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            // set date picker as current date
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month,
                    day);
        }
        return null;
    }


private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
            year = selectedYear;
            month = selectedMonth;
            day = selectedDay;

            // set selected date into textview
            mbirthdayView.setText(  (day)+(".")+(month + 1)+(".")+(year));

            // set selected date into datepicker also
            dpResult.init(year, month, day, null);

        }
    };
```

and finally you can call datepicker like this:

```
showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
```